# Show header but not footer in grouped tableView with automatic dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview

I am trying to have headers in my grouped tableView but not footers.  I am creating headers with:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

     let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header") as! DateHeaderTableViewHeaderFooterView
     ...
     return headerView
}
```

I have setup the tableView in storyboard to use automatic dimensions for all cells and headers and footers.

I assumed because I didn't provide any footers, they would not exist however footers are being added to each section.  Also all the headers and footers have a gray background.

I tried unchecking the footer automatic dimension and selecting a value however the lowest value it can accept is 1 and still the footer shows up.

How can I have headers but not footers and change the background color of the header?

I can achieve what I want using a plain tableView however the headers are pinned to the top which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 13 + iOS 15 device
You have to set UITableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding to zero also.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683431